# How to add a password when selecting one of two options in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post and I'm not particularly versed in code, so please be patient and bear with me as I try to explain my query as clear as possible.

I have a spreadsheet which has a data validation tab where I can either choose "Actual" or "Budget" - depending on what I choose these figures will then be loaded into a SQL Table.

What I want to do, is when I choose "Budget" as one of my two options, I would like it to ask me for a password in my VBA Code.

So from the following drop down options, they can choose either and this is what I want to happen

Actual - someone else can edit the figures

Budget - they would need a password first before any editing.

I hope that makes sense and that someone can assist me, thanks in advance!

Dan

Comment: Why has this been voted down - I would appreciate some feedback, so I don't make the same mistakes in future posts

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the protect function from excel :
[Excel protect function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-dbf706e0-ba22-4a08-84d8-552db16eef11)
 [VBA protect function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff840611.aspx)

It can be accessed with VBA like this :

```
    'Lock, see second link for a full list of availables options on what is locked or not
    ActiveSheet.Protect "yourPasswordHere", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

    ' Unlock
     ActiveSheet.Unprotect "yourPasswordHere"
```

Depending on how your worksheet and VBA is built, you may protect the sheet when the user select the budget, and unprotect when he changes to the other options.

However, this solution make your budget table still visible for the user, he can look at it without password, but he can't modify the values.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will now give that a try 

Regards
Dan